# How to store string characters to a list in an order that matches a randomly selected word beforehand for advanced Hangman game

Tags: python-3.x

I am a student that took one class of Java Freshman year (am now a senior). This summer I decided to start coding again. I am programming all the past projects that I miserably failed at in my CompSci class.

I decided to start learning python, and it's slowly coming back to me.

Anyways, I am working on a hangman game. I made a list

```
wordList = ['beloit', 'friend', 'transcript', 'feeling', 'internship', 
'guarding', 'feeling']
```

which I randomly select a word using the random.choice() function.

Here is the rest of my code:

```
while guesses == 0:
   letter = input('Please guess a letter: ')
   print('Letter is: ' + letter)

   if letter not in word:
       print('Nice guess, but wrong')
       failure -= 1
       print('You have {} trie(s) left.'.format(failure))
       if failure == 0:
           print('You lost')
           break

   elif letter in word:
        print(letter + ' is in the secret word!')
        storeList.append(letter)
        print(storeList)
```

After running a few times, while purposefully showing the random word "guarding" my output is:

```
guarding 

Please guess a letter: b
Letter is: b
Nice guess, but wrong
You have 14 tries left.
Please guess a letter: d
Letter is: d
d is in the secret word!
['d']
Please guess a letter: g
Letter is: g
g is in the secret word!
['d', 'g']
Please guess a letter: u
Letter is: u
u is in the secret word!
['d', 'g', 'u']
```

I am trying to store the input variables from 'letter' in the correct order so it shows

```
['g', 'u', '', '', 'd'] ...
```

> I am not necessarily looking for a full answer, but just some hints on the methods I should use to achieve this.
>
> Any other advice is appreciated, thanks again

Comment: you need to use `storeList[word.index(letter)] = letter` but somewhere before this you should initialize the length of your list, ie `storeList = [None]*len(word)`

Comment: I did `storeList[word.index(letter)] = letter` it passes into `storeList` correctly. _My output:_ `Letter is: e, e is in the secret word! ['f', 'e', '_', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'g']` How do I pass a the same letter, in this case E, into the other spot when given a word with multiple of the same letter, like **feeling**?

Comment: due to the repeating nature of the letters, you can decide to fill all the spaces with the same letter at once. eg: `import re;for i in re.finditer(letter,word):
           storeList[i.start()] = letter`

Answer (score 0):

You could initialise the list as a series of ""s that line up with your word's `len()`. (`["","","","",""]`) and then if they get it write, look up where the letter is and then address the list and add it (`list[1] = "o"`), then the user might guess `c` and you could check where that is and then add it with `list[0] = c` etc. (I'm using the word code as an example). :)

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are saying! Thank you, that helps.

Comment: Let me know if you would like me to add more detail :)

Comment: Would I have to adjust the empty list dependent upon the length of the word? Since it's chosen randomly, how would I account for the extra characters for longer words? Or does 'len()' help with that?

Comment: Hint: for every number >0 in Len(), you want to append a "" to your list.